# 'Series' object error with in my data attribute 'columns' it is columns and pandas

Tags: series

I have Series error:'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' y is include one 'id' and one dfloat column what I would like to use.
features = y[y.columns[-1:]]
features

Comment: its difficult to understand what you are trying to do. can you please give more details on what are you trying to do, what is the issue, error and some more details of your code. for more details about what to include in question, you can visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks your answer. I will ask with more details next time. I think I solved. but now I have another error.